# PowerShell parse each line and extract values after colon

Tags: powershell, substring

I have `$body` variable:

```
Name:john Doe

Location:New York

Role:engineer
```

I want, for each line, to get values after `:`.

**Desired output:**

```
John doe
New York
engineer
```

So far I have this code:

```
foreach ($part in $body.Split(':')) {
    echo $part
}
```

**Current output:**

```
Name
john Doe

Location
New York

Role
engineer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing to much about your data in $body, this should work:

```
$body = "Name:john Doe
Location:New York
Role:engineer"

$body.split([Environment]::NewLine) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split(":")[1]
}
```

First we need to split on every line that is in your variable. Then for each line, we need to split on ":" and because you only want the part from the right hand side, we use the index 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the value after the colon too for some PowerShell scripts I was working on... it turns out that we don't need to parse it with string manipulations, because the PowerShell command actually returns an object...

the command `get-netipaddress` had the info i wanted:

- ```
  get-netipaddress
  ```

  [image: get-netipaddress result]

filtering out results i don't need with `where` command:

- ```
  get-netipaddress `
    | Where { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet" } `
    | Where { $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" }
  ```

  [image: where clause]

accessing the `IPAddress` property:

- ```
  $ethernetInterfaceInfo = get-netipaddress `
    | Where { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet" } `
    | Where { $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4" }
  $ethernetInterfaceInfo.IPAddress
  ```

  [image: accessing the IPAddress property]